# How to limit the search results in Angular12

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to limit the results that shows in the table. I've tried to put ngrepeat with limitTo, but it didn't work.

Here's my code:

`busqueda.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-busqueda',
  templateUrl: './busqueda.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./busqueda.component.css'],
})


export class BusquedaComponent implements OnInit {


  filterTerm: string;

  items = [];

  actas = [{
      "nombre": "Lede, Lourdes del Mar",
      "DNI": "40.775.265",
      "FechaNacimiento": "17/02/1998",
      "LugarNacimiento": "La Rioja, Capital",
      "ActaNacimiento": "VER"
    }
    
  ];

  //paginación
  pageOfItems: Array<any>;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(123);

    this.items = Array(150).fill(0).map((x, i) => ({ id: (i + 1)}));
  }

  onChangePage(pageOfItems: Array<any>) {
    // update current page of items
    this.pageOfItems = pageOfItems;
}

}
```

`busqueda.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
<h1 class="titulo text-center">Buscar un acta</h1>
<div class="busqueda">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..." [(ngModel)]="filterTerm">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="txt text-center">La búsqueda se puede realizar por nombre, apellido, DNI, fecha de nacimiento o lugar de nacimiento.</p>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="tabla">
                <th>Apellido y Nombre</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                <th>Lugar de Nacimiento</th>
                <th>Acta de Nacimiento</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let acta of actas | filter:filterTerm">
            <tr class="tabla">
                <td class="txt-left">{{acta.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{acta.DNI}}</td>
                <td>{{acta.FechaNacimiento}}</td>
                <td>{{acta.LugarNacimiento}}</td>
                <td>{{acta.ActaNacimiento}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I don't know how to continue, any help it will help me a lot.
The searchbox it's working OK, it show the list, maybe I can limit to 10 or 5 results, because it will be a lot to search in database when the program are running, this is why I'm here.

Comment: I don't understand. If your are calling an API, can't it return only the number of results you want? And even if not, can't you keep only the items you want in the JS array?

Comment: check the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) `let acta of actas | filter:filterTerm|slice:0:10` -or use slice javascript-

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that you can implement is limit the results that is coming from the backend, which would make the code clean in fe and lightweight.

Another workaround would be limiting the loop using index, upto the limit that you want.